# How to use the scroll bar event on an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, events

I want to change the background of an element when the scroll bar is beside that element. How can I do that?
I used 'scroll' event, but it didn't work.

```
<div id="skill">This is Skill</div>


var about = document.getElementById('about');
 about.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 about.style.background='green';
});
```

like this, when I click on that section the background changes:

```
about.addEventListener('click', function() {
 about.style.background='green'});
```

Comment: You're probably scrolling the HTML body (the page) and not the item itself. This is why the scroll even is not triggering for the about container

Comment: I think, you should give the fixed height to that div and add the scroll css in property

Comment: Your logic is sound, but you are checking for scrolling on the actual `about` element, whereas I assume you are scrolling the main page scroll bar.
Therefore, target that scroll bar in your code: `window.addEventListener("scroll", doSomething()};`

Comment: Yes, I mean when I use the page scroll bar. @LucaDeNardi

Comment: I think you have to clarify what you mean by "I want the change the background of an element when the scroll bar is besides that element". Does it mean when the about section becomes visible on scrolling? When it's in the middle of the screen? I don't think the question is clear enough

Comment: sorry about my english. yes I mean when the about section becomes visible on scrolling. do something in javascript@LucaDeNardi

Answer (score 1):

What I guess from your question is, you want to add background when page scrolled.

```js
var about = document.getElementById('about');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  about.style.background = 'green';
});
```

```css
body{
  height:800px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="about">This is Skill</div>
</body>
<html>
```